# how to color closed polylines in tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, colors, polyline

I would like to color the area enclosed by any closed non-intersecting polyline. Heres an
example of what I want:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master, x, y):
        self.master = master
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=x, height=y)
        self.canvas.pack()
        polyline = self.canvas.create_line(10, 10, 10, 20, 200, 300, 250, 150, 10, 10)


x, y = 500, 500
root = tk.Tk()
gui = GUI(root, x, y)
root.mainloop()
```

I would like to color the area defined by the polyline canvas object.

Comment: Have you tried to use a polygon instead of polyline? Try replacing this line `polyline = self.canvas.create_line(10, 10, 10, 20, 200, 300, 250, 150, 10, 10)` with this: `polyline = self.canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 10, 20, 200, 300, 250, 150, 10, 10, outline="black", fill="blue")`. You can set both fill color and outline color for polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a polygon instead of a polyline. In this case, you can set both fill and outline colors. Here is a usage example:

```
import tkinter as tk


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master, x, y):
        self.master = master
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=x, height=y)
        self.canvas.pack()
        polyline = self.canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 10, 20, 200, 300, 250, 150, 10, 10, outline="green", fill="blue")


x, y = 500, 500
root = tk.Tk()
gui = GUI(root, x, y)
root.mainloop()
```